# Halide sum loops nesting

Tags: sum, nested-loops, reduction, halide

Printed loops nesting for Halide::sum is not equivalent for optimal as written in [tutorial](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/c87c66444e5b3cdd8690f82cae069b97ea6673a4/tutorial/lesson_09_update_definitions.cpp#L706).

This code provides separate loops for zero initialization and summation.

```cpp
  Halide::Func f("f");
  Halide::Var x("x");
  Halide::RDom r(0, 3);

  f(x) = Halide::sum(r + x);
  f.print_loop_nest();

  f.realize(10);
```

output:

```
produce f:
  for x:
    produce sum:
      for x:
        sum(...) = ...
      for x:
        for r4:
          sum(...) = ...
    consume sum:
      f(...) = ...
```

Can fuse this loops or it does not impact on performance? Thanks!

---

**Update:** Fuse like this:

```
produce f:
  for x:
    produce sum:
      for x:
        sum(...) = ...
        for r4:
          sum(...) = ...
    consume sum:
      f(...) = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of print_loop_nest being confusing. That inner loop over x is of size 1, so it goes away. The compiled loop nest is the one you want. The outer loop over x is the non-trivial one, so this is what's really happening:

```
produce f:
  for x:
    produce sum:
      sum(...) = ...
      for r4:
        sum(...) = ...
    consume sum:
      f(...) = ...
```